# Elasticsearch NEST nested query not working c#

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an ElasticSearch query issue I cannot resolve that happened when upgrading from 6.4 to 6.8:

My Schema has this

```
...
              "levels" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "dynamic" : "false",
                "properties" : {
                  "curriculaCount" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "hoursEarned" : {
                    "type" : "half_float"
                  },
                  "levelCode" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
...
```

I have a query that works just fine in Kibana dev tools:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "banner.levels",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "banner.levels.levelCode": "UG"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "banner.levels.curriculaCount": {
                  "gt": 0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "banner.levels.hoursEarned": {
                  "lte": 29
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My corresponding c# code used to work in 6.4 but is failing in 6.8 and no amount of trying yields me a successful query:

```
       queries.Add(new NestedQuery()
                {
                    Path = Infer.Field<BannerPerson>(x => x.banner.levels),
                    
                    Query = new BoolQuery()
                    {
                        Must = new List<QueryContainer>()
                        {
                            new NumericRangeQuery()
                            {
                                Field = Infer.Field<BannerPerson>(x => x.banner.levels.First().hoursEarned),
                                LessThan = 30
                            },
                            new NumericRangeQuery()
                            {
                                Field = Infer.Field<BannerPerson>(x => x.banner.levels.First().curriculaCount),
                                GreaterThan = 0
                            },
                            new TermQuery()
                            {
                                Field = Infer.Field<BannerPerson>(x => x.banner.levels.First().levelCode.Suffix("keyword")),
                                Value = "UG"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Anything I do yields me the dreaded "Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST..."

I wish there were a way to get a more detailed error message...

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I finally fixed the issue and it was unrelated to the code above.  Clearing all indices, reloading the schema and then fresh data fixed all the wonky behavior

Answer (score 0):

If updating elasticsearch to a new version, I recommend clearing out the old indices, reloading the schema and reloading fresh data.  That fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).